# Cores in a aws cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am using a 10 core r4.8xlarge cluster. AWS documentation  https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/virtualcores/ says that each EC2 Instance Type of r4.8xlarge contains a Virtual Core Count of 16. Question 1. Does this mean there are 160 cores in parallel (16 cores for each executor. By this I also ask, is a core = a spark executor)? Q2. Spark documentation says

```
The number of cores allocated to the Spark Streaming application must be more than the number of receivers. Otherwise the system will receive data, but not be able to process it.
```

Q2. If I am going to create 15 receivers for my spark streaming job, should I set my spark.executor.cores = 15 or above. Or should I increase the total cores of my cluster from 10 to 15?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to Q2:

You can set `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled` to `true` (it's `false` by default) to dynamically allocate executors, when running on EMR, its good to take advantage of this.

Read about it [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#dynamic-allocation) and [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#dynamic-resource-allocation)

Comment: Thanks for the advice